# Android - How can I invalidate/remove specific URL s from saved cache using okhttp-retrofit.?

Tags: java, android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

I implemented cache in my android project using retrofit and okhttp. Its working fine in online and offline modes. On the server side, E-Tag and Cache Control mechanism is implemented to manage the cache expiry and validation. The minimum validity of a response is set to 5 minutes by default from the server side.

My requirement is that, during some specific user interactions, the server response, especially the home page response will be changed. If the user immediately return to home page, the changes will not be reflected since the  expiration time is set to 5 minutes.

I need to delete the cached copy of home response so that the home page will be reloaded with changes. I don't want to delete the whole cache, just this specific one. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

`@Headers("Cache-Control: no-cache")` 
on the method should work.

If you want to do it dynamically you can add a 
`@Header("Cache-Control")`

String cacheControl parameter and pass null or "no-cache"